# Bad cross-reference using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, titlesec

When I define two new level using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), the reference doesn't work correctly.

This is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% First level
\titleclass{\exemple}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{exemple}[section]
\titleformat{\exemple}[runin]{}{\theexemple}{0em}{Exemple \ }[\quad]
\titlespacing{\exemple}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{1em}

\renewcommand{\theexemple}{\thesection.\roman{exemple}}

% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% second one
\titleclass{\suiteexemple}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{suiteexemple}[section]

\titleformat{\suiteexemple}[runin]{}{\thesuiteexemple}{0em}{Suite de l'exemple \ }[\quad]

\titlespacing{\suiteexemple}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\thesuiteexemple}{\thesection.\roman{suiteexemple}}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\section{one} \label{sec:one}

...

\exemple{First exemple} 
\label{ex:one}

\exemple{Second example}

\section{two}

...

Reference to exemple : \ref{ex:one}

\end{document}
```

The reference is displayed as "1", but it should be "1.1" (the exemple counter is not displayed).

If you comment the code between the `% ------` the reference is correctly displayed.

Do you know any workaround on this problem?

Comment: I get "Reference to exemple : 1" (just copied an pasted from the PDF file).

Comment: Yep, but it should be "Reference to exemple : 1.1"

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to include the result of a compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how `\titleclass` works.

With `\titleclass{\exemple}{straight}[\subsection]` you're inserting a new numbering level between `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. So `\example` becomes level 3 and `\subsubsection` is shifted to level 4.

With the following `\titleclass{\subexemple}{straight}[\subsection]` you do the same, so `\subexemple` becomes level 3 and `\exemple` is shifted to level 5.

Therefore, with the usual value of 3 for `secnumdepth`, `\exemple` loses its numbering and the `\label{ex:one}` command will refer to the last "refstepped" command which happened at `\section{one}`.

You probably have better to define `\suiteexemple` in terms of `\example*` or saying

```
\titleclass{\suiteexemple}{straight}[\exemple]
```

Comment: Ok, I get it! I thought `\titleclass...[\subsection]` define something "at the same level" than `\subsection` I should define both command in term of `\subsection`