# Multiple sections on same level with diferent labels

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec

This is a follow up to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125217/how-do-i-add-a-box-as-a-prefix-to-sections-or-float-a-box-left-of-sections) question.

I would like to have multiple subsections with different labels (in this situation the sign off boxes) all in the same numbering sequence. My attempt at this has broken the numbering all together.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[explicit,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

%Heading formatting
\titleformat{\part}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \thepart:}{0.5em}{#1}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{\TIndent}{\llap{\makebox[0.5\TIndent][l]{\thesection}\hfill}#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}

%Trainee section signoff
\newcounter{trainee}
\titleclass{\trainee}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\trainee}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\llap{\smash{\makebox[\TIndent][l]{\normalfont\TeBox}}}\thesubsection. #1}
\titlespacing*{\trainee}
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thetrainee}{\Alph{trainee}}

%Trainer section signoff
\newcounter{trainer}
\titleclass{\trainer}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\trainer}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\llap{\smash{\makebox[\TIndent][l]{\normalfont\TrBox}}}\thesubsection. #1}
\titlespacing*{\trainer}
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thetrainer}{\Alph{trainer}}

%Defines the sign off indent distance
\newlength\TIndent
\setlength\TIndent{9em}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

%Trainee box
\newcommand\TeBox{%
\fbox{\footnotesize%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\\[1.2em]
\hline
\\[-.8em]
Trainee & Date \vspace{-.4em}
\end{tabular}}%
}

%Trainer box
\newcommand\TrBox{%
\fbox{\footnotesize%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\\[1.2em]
\hline
\\[-.8em]
Trainer & Date \vspace{-.4em}
\end{tabular}}%
}

\setitemize{label={\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}},leftmargin=*}

\newcommand\Text{% just to generate text for the example
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel,
wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.}

\begin{document}
\part{Personnel Introduction}

\lipsum[4]

    \section{Division Personnel}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{3cm}{0pt}
        \leavevmode\trainee{Headquarters}

        \Text
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Name Name
        \item Name Name
        \end{itemize}

        \trainer{Production Department}

        \Text
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Name Name

        \begin{center}
        SECONDARY GROUP
        \end{center}

        \item Name Name
        \item Name Name
        \item Name Name
        \end{itemize}
    \end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sign Off Example]

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111046/bad-cross-reference-using-titlesec?

Comment: Inside the `\titleformat{\trainer}` and `\titleformat{\trainee}` you're using the `subsection` counter. Perhaps you meant to use `\thetrainee` and `\thetrainer` instead of `\thesubsection`? Im not sure if you want trainee and trainer to share counter.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina My intention is for trainee and trainer to share a counter but that doesn't seem to work. I was just guessing that this would work, I want to make sure I have syntax correct or see if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @egreg that post helps my understanding on `\titleclass` but I don't know how it pertains to my numbering being broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieva what you want using just one new sectional unit `trainex` and a command with an optional argument together with a conditional test to decide whether to use "Trainer" or "Trainee":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[explicit,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

%Heading formatting
\titleformat{\part}[block]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}{\partname\ \thepart:}{0.5em}{#1}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{\TIndent}{\llap{\makebox[0.5\TIndent][l]{\thesection}\hfill}#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}

%Trainex section signoff
% will be used for both, depending on an optional argument
\newcounter{trainex}
\titleclass{\trainex}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\trainex}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\llap{\smash{\makebox[\TIndent][l]{\normalfont\TeBox}}}\thetrainex. #1}
\titlespacing*{\trainex}
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thetrainex}{\Alph{trainex}}

\def\trainexx{}

% Here we decide whether to use "Trainee" or "Trainer" in the box
% by default, \trainey uses "Trainer"; if the optional argument is "e"
% then "Trainee" will be used.
\newcommand\trainey[2][r]{%
\if#1r\relax
\renewcommand\trainexx{Trainer}
\else
\if#1e
\renewcommand\trainexx{Trainee}
\fi\fi
\trainex{#2}
}

%Defines the sign off indent distance
\newlength\TIndent
\setlength\TIndent{9em}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

%Trainee box
\newcommand\TeBox{%
\fbox{\footnotesize%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\\[1.2em]
\hline
\\[-.8em]
\trainexx & Date \vspace{-.4em}
\end{tabular}}%
}

%Trainer box
\newcommand\TrBox{%
\fbox{\footnotesize%
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\\[1.2em]
\hline
\\[-.8em]
Trainer & Date \vspace{-.4em}
\end{tabular}}%
}

\setitemize{label={\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}},leftmargin=*}

\newcommand\Text{% just to generate text for the example
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel,
wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.}

\begin{document}
\part{Personnel Introduction}

\lipsum[4]

    \section{Division Personnel}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{3cm}{0pt}
        \leavevmode\trainey[e]{Headquarters}

        \Text
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Name Name
        \item Name Name
        \end{itemize}

        \trainey{Production Department}

        \Text
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Name Name

        \begin{center}
        SECONDARY GROUP
        \end{center}

        \item Name Name
        \item Name Name
        \item Name Name
        \end{itemize}
    \end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the end I chose this method. It allows for flexibility on the input of the signoff box. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @Beaunus You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to use `subsection` to hold my numbering and I manually increment the numbers. I tested it and it works like a charm!

```
%Set initial subsection counter
\setcounter{subsection}{1}

%Trainee section signoff
\newcounter{trainee}
\titleclass{\trainee}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\trainee}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\stepcounter{subsection}\llap{\smash{\makebox[\TIndent][l]{\normalfont\TeBox}}}\thesubsection. #1}
\titlespacing*{\trainee}                   ^ %Increment subsection counter here
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thetrainee}{\Alph{subsection}}

%Trainer section signoff
\newcounter{trainer}
\titleclass{\trainer}{straight}[\section]
\titleformat{\trainer}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\stepcounter{subsection}\llap{\smash{\makebox[\TIndent][l]{\normalfont\TrBox}}}\thesubsection. #1}
\titlespacing*{\trainer}                   ^ %Increment subsection counter here
    {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thetrainer}{\Alph{subsection}}
```

[image: Manual Counter]

Comment: No need to manually increment counters; please see my updated answer.